Can StateFlow have multiple collectors? Unable to understand the difference between StateFlow and SharedFlow
Created below MutableStateFlow for understanding how collecting works using StateFlow. Is the below code valid? How we can right correctly?
val _mutableStateFlow = MutableStateFlow(0)
val stateFlow: StateFlow = _mutableStateFlow

launch {
  stateFlow.collect { value ->
    println("Collector 1 received: $value")
  }
}

launch {
 stateFlow.collect { value ->
   println("Collector 2 received: $value")
 }
}

launch {
 repeat(3) { i ->
   delay(2000)
   mutableStateFlow.tryEmit(i)
 }
}

Output -
Collector 1 received: 0
Collector 2 received: 0

after 2 second
Collector 1 received: 1
Collector 2 received: 1

after 2 second
Collector 1 received: 2
Collector 2 received: 2

How collecting works with StateFlow and SharedFlow?

StateFlow is a specialised implementation of SharedFlow. And as a SharedFlow it can have multiple collectors and will share emitted values among the collectors.
StateFlow always has a value and only emits a new value if it is different from the previous one.
As per documentation, MutableStateFlow(initialValue) is a shared flow with the following parameters::
val shared = MutableSharedFlow(
    replay = 1,
    onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
)
shared.tryEmit(initialValue) // emit the initial value
val state = shared.distinctUntilChanged() // get StateFlow-like behavior


Unlike SharedFlow can StateFlow also have multiple collectors?

They both can. @r_dev
